# Liquid markup for email templates

Tags: liquid

Can I have HTML in liquid markup?

I am new to this space and would like to know what conditionals can I include?

Answer (score 0):

go to the website and look at the first example http://liquidmarkup.org/

you can use HTML in liquid markup